# Calling localhost with port 3000 from Faraday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rspec, faraday

Currently I have 2 micro services API,I am trying to test the connection between the two micro services API using Rspec(Ruby Spec), and using Ruby Faraday.

When I

`Faraday.get "localhost:3000/api/v1"`

I am having these error:

`Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:3000 (Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 3000`

But when I curl `localhost:3000` The response works fine.

Comment: add `http://` in url

Comment: Already did, also tried `https://`

Comment: Are you running rails server on default port 3000? While running the rspec, is the server running?

Comment: I am using Crystal lang Kemal, at localhost:3000

Comment: I have a same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: Just to be certain: I was building the connection using `Faraday.new(url: "localhost:3000")`... and by changing it to `Faraday.new(url: "https://localhost:3000")` I was able to move forward